# Move BoundingRect of InkStroke to 0;0

Tags: c#, .net, paint, win-universal-app

How can I nove `BoundingRect` to coordinates: X=0;Y=0?
I need to save every `InkStroke` painted by user on `InkCanvas` as image separetly in Windows Universal App.

To save final image I'm using Win2D, but this just save cropped Canvas from `<0,0>` to `<BoundingRectHeight,BoundingRectWidth>`...

```
private async Task SaveToImage(string id, InkStroke stroke, float width, float height)
{
    CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
    CanvasRenderTarget offscreen = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, width, height, 96);
    using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = offscreen.CreateDrawingSession())
    {
        ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
        ds.DrawInk(new InkStroke[] { stroke });
    }

    StorageFile f = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(id + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (IRandomAccessStream output = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        await offscreen.SaveAsync(output, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);
        await output.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this approach is probably wrong.

So, I decide to do this way:

- Draw given stroke into Offscreen canvas by Win2D
- Offscreen canvas save into InMememoryRandomAccessStream
- Crop given stream into WritableBitmap
- Open StorageFile for read/write
- Create BitmapEncoder and set Pixel data from WriteableBitmap

Full example you can found at my [GitHub](https://github.com/Sebosek/Sebastian.WebInk)